# Wiring up the Page_PreInit event manually, with AutoEventWireup set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling, page-lifecycle

If the `AutoEventWireup` attribute is set to `false`, the events need to be wired up manually.  However, I cannot seem to get the `Page_PreInit` to fire.  I would guess that I might be making the wireup happen too late (once we're already past `Page_PreInit`), but I'm not sure where else to put the wireups.

For example...

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e)
    PreInit += new EventHandler(Page_PreInit);
    Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
}

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_PreInit event fired!<br>");  //this is never reached
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Page_Load event fired!<br>");
}
```

The above code results in "Page_Load event fired!" being displayed, but nothing from `Page_PreInit`. I tried `base.OnInit(e)` both before AND after the wireups, and that had no effect.

The graph shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) says that the `OnInit` method actually comes after the `PreInit` event.  With that in mind, I tried overriding `OnPreInit` and doing the same thing --- no effect.

The MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx) explicitly says that in the event of `AutoEventWireup` set to `false`, the events can be wired up in an overriden `OnInit`. The example they use is `Page_Load`, and of course that works just like it does for me, but they don't address that this doesn't seem to work for the `Page_PreInit` event.

**My question is: how can I get the `Page_PreInit` event wired up in the case of `AutoEventWireup` set to `false`?**

I understand there are alternatives as listed on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx), such as using the page's constructor.  I'd like to know specifically how to do like they suggest with `OnInit`.

Comment: You've got to do it in the constructor or before calling `base.OnInit`.

Comment: Unfortunately putting the lines above base.OnInit(e) has no effect, and aiming for an earlier event (such as OnPreInit) still won't reach the Page_PreInit event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The base implementation of the [OnPreInit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.onpreinit.aspx) method is responsible for raising the `PreInit` event. Since your override calls that implementation *before* registering your `PreInit` handler, it will indeed not be called.

Try calling the base class' method *after* registering the handler:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    PreInit += new EventHandler(Page_PreInit);
    Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);

    // And only then:
    base.OnPreInit(e);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted this code is overriding `OnPreInit` instead of `OnInit`.

Answer (score 0):

add all the event in initialization area:

```
public WebName()
      {
         this.event+=TAB Key
      }
```